# compile error when using parenthesis in visual studio but pass in g++/clang++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am developing cross-platform project, and I found something strange.
in visual studio, the following code will fail. But g++/clang++ in Linux environment can compile without error. In addition, I search for keyword on VS, but found nothing. Anyone the reason?

```
int main(){
  ({;});
  return 0;
}
```

```
error C2059: syntax error: '{'
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

Visual Studio version I have : Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019, Version 16.5.1

Comment: @JaMiT I think that's what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, it is interpreted as vc++. In c++, ; marks end of statement. So your code 
({;}); is exactly taken by compiler as 1  ({;  and 2 }); as a statement  which is synaxtically not correct. Check syntax of wrting code in c++. I dont know about g++/clang. Sorry there.

Comment: By your theory `for(;;)` should be illegal, except it's not.

Comment: No, that is syntaxically correct

Answer (score 0):

Compiling with `clang++` using the `-pedantic -Werror` flags we see

```
dummy.cc:2:4: error: use of GNU statement expression extension [-Werror,-Wgnu-statement-expression]
  ({;});
   ^
1 error generated.
```

The MSVC compiler (`cl`, typically used by Visual Studio) does not support many non-standard extensions specific to GCC, including its [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

In this case, the block `{;}` is treated as a (useless) statement expression:

```cpp
{
  /* nothing */
  ;
  /* nothing */
}
```

The outermost parentheses (`(`...`)`) are there to ensure the parser treats the block as an *expression*, rather than a more typical empty code block.